# Boot Options for different OS

Tags: noobs, setup

I have installed NOOBS 1.9.2(Offline and network install) in Pi3 Board. On booting only Raspbain OS option available and not listing other different OS to be installed or booting.How to show other options of OS for booting

Answer (score 1):

To free up SD card space, the NOOBS package now only contains the Raspbian archive. To install Arch, Pidora, OpenELEC, RaspBMC or RISC OS you will require a network connection. If network cable is plugged in, then check your network, router, etc.

Comment: Dear Maxim.Thank you very much for your prompt help. I will check network connection and let you latter.